# Bootstrap date range picker - disable user input

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using `bsDaterangepicker` (`"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.3"`) with `Angular 4`.

I need to prevent the user from entering date values rather than selecting through the datepicker.

I have found some code which prevents all the keyEvents (`<input onkeydown="return false" ... />`). But in my case user shall be able to delete or copy the values in date range picker.

Comment: Would `readonly` flag on the picker not work?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. Thanks @WolfieeifloW

Comment: You should try to look up for the properties of the tag at least first.